The following error occurs when executing "npm run build" through .exec on the node server
Error: Command failed: npm install & npm run build sh: 1: tsc: not found npm WARN deprecated @motionone/vue@10.16.4: Motion One for Vue is deprecated. Use Oku Motion instead https://oku-ui.com/motion
2 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 1 high) To address all issues, run: npm audit fix Run `npm audit` for details.

I am trying to build project on node server.
